# Apache Bean PTransform to PCollection

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam

I am trying to consume records from kafka and write them to BigQuery , also following the online documentation found here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/

Most of the examples posted here are with PCollection, I have Ptransform in my code

Any idea if we can use the writeQuery on PTransofrm or a way to convert PTransform to PCollection

Code for consuming records from kafa is below

```
public class BeamConsoleConsumer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String tableSpec = "project-id.kafka.sample";

    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    Schema schema =
        new Schema.Parser()
            .parse(new File("schema.avsc"));

    PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<KafkaRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>>> input =
        KafkaIO.<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>read()
            .withBootstrapServers(
                "kafak-server-url")
            .withTopic("sample-topis") // use
            // withTopics(List<String>) to read from multiple topics.
            .withKeyDeserializer(
                ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.of(
                    "schema-registry-key-deserializer"))
            .withValueDeserializer(
                ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.of(
                    "schema-registry-value-deserializer"))
            .withConsumerConfigUpdates(
                ImmutableMap.of(
                    ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                    "sample-group-id",
                    CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG,
                    "SSL",
                    SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,
                    "truststore.jks",
                    SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,
                    "password",
                    SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,
                    "keystore.jks",
                    SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,
                    "password",
                    SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG,
                    "password",
                    ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
                    "latest",
                    ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,
                    600000));

    pipeline
        .apply(input)
        .apply(
            "ExtractRecord",
            ParDo.of(
                new DoFn<
                    KafkaRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>,
                    KafkaRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>>() {
                  @DoFn.ProcessElement
                  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    KafkaRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> record =
                        (KafkaRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>) c.element();
                    KV<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> log = record.getKV();
                    System.out.println("Key Obtained: " + log.getKey());
                    System.out.println("Value Obtained: " + log.getValue().toString());
                    c.output(record);
                  }
                }));
    

    PipelineResult run = pipeline.run();
    run.waitUntilFinish(Duration.standardSeconds(1000));
  }
}
```